# How to get calling URL in URL Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5

I am using URL Redirection in ASP.net like this page

```
http://xyz:6477/BoxOffice/Events/353454
```

Redirect to >>>

```
http://xyz:6477/BoxOffice/Events.aspx?EventId=353454
```

I want to get URL on page load of event page

```
http://xyz:6477/BoxOffice/Events/353454
```

Comment: HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
//To get referrer
//in C#
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer; 

//in vb
Dim MyUrl As Uri = Request.UrlReferrer 

//To get current
//in C#

Uri currrenturl = Request.Url;
//in vb
Dim currentUrl As Uri = Request.Url
```

If you are using routing then use

```
    //c#
    string ref = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;
```

Comment: UrlReferrer give me URL of previous calling page not this url

Comment: do you want url of current page?

Comment: I want Url of current page yes but not redirected I want this http://xyz:6477/BoxOffice/Events/353454

Comment: are you using url routing or url rewriting?

Comment: @KrishanuDey: The "Referrer" header is not always reliable, therefore, the `UrlReferrer` property is not always reliable.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : I know. But is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @KrishanuDey: yes. Send that information in some reliable way, like in the query string. Add a "originalUrl=url" parameter.